# Problem in php ajax post value

Tags: php, ajax, post

I want to make a php ajax post.(post value without refresh the page) here is my code. It can return the value and show in `<div id="msg"></div>`, But I also want to use this value.

In @benhowdle89 's help, I made `$name= "<div id='msg'></div>"`. but when I use `echo $name`, in the source code, I can see `<div id='msg'></div>(html tag)`, this is not a pure value, so I tried to use strip_tags, but the value lost. it seems the left the ajax pointed div tag, the value also gone.  Still waiting for help...

index.php

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function saveUserInfo() { 
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg"); 
    var f = document.user_info; 
    var userName = f.user_name.value; 
    var url = "value.php"; 
    var postStr   = "user_name="+ userName; 
    var ajax = false; 

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        if (ajax.overrideMimeType) { 
            ajax.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); 
        } 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
        try { 
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } catch (e) { 
            try { 
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            } catch (e) { 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    if (!ajax) { 
        window.alert("wrong"); 
        return false; 
    } 

    ajax.open("POST", url, true); 
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    ajax.send(postStr); 
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) { 
            var myPhpVariable = ajax.responseText; 
            msg.innerHTML = myPhpVariable; 
            // myPhpVariable is now a variable which you can use
            alert( myPhpVariable ); 
        } 
    } 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body>
<?php
echo $name="<div id='msg'></div>";
$name1=strip_tags($name);
$name2 = explode("|",$name1);
$namea=$name2[0];
$nameb=$name2[1];
?>
<form name="user_info" id="user_info" method="post"> 
<input name="user_name" type="hidden" value="abc|def" /><br /> 
<input type="button" value="abc|def" onClick="saveUserInfo()"> 
</form> 
</body>
```

value.php

```
<?php 
echo $_POST["user_name"]; 
?>
```

This is what I want. post value from index.php, then get the value by self without refresh the page. one botton with two values, I want explode them and finally get `$namea` and `$nameb`. I want use them in other php part.

Comment: Where do you want to use the posted value? In PHP or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the ajax response into a javascript variable, then you can manipulate it from there:

```
var myPhpVariable = ajax.responseText;
msg.innerHTML = myPhpVariable;
alert( myPhpVariable );
```

Here is a working javascript example (full code):

```
function saveUserInfo() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("msg");
    var f = document.user_info;
    var userName = f.user_name.value;
    var url = "value.php";
    var postStr   = "user_name="+ userName;
    var ajax = false;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (ajax.overrideMimeType) {
            ajax.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            }
        }
    }

    if (!ajax) {
        window.alert("wrong");
        return false;
    }

    ajax.open("POST", url, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(postStr);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var myPhpVariable = ajax.responseText;
            msg.innerHTML = myPhpVariable;
            // myPhpVariable is now a variable which you can use
            alert( myPhpVariable );
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP file would look like:

```
$postVar = $_POST["user_name"];
$postVarArr = explode('|', $postVar);

// will show abc
//echo $postVarArr['0'];

// will show def
echo $postVarArr['1'];
```

Comment: I tried add ajax response after my code `var msg = document.getElementById("msg"); ` but in firebug, it show wrong...

Comment: Right, but if you set `var myPhpVariable = ajax.responseText;` then you won't have the HTML entities, you'll just have the response (which will be the value).

Comment: Excuse me, I still not know where to add this code, I can not pass the test.

Comment: For I am newbie, how to use myPhpVariable?

Comment: @yuli chika What are you trying to accomplish? The variable `myPhpVariable` is a javascript variable, and you can do whatever you want with it. You said, "But I also want to use this value." How do you want to use it? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Ok, you can do that in either PHP or javascript. So, in your `input` field, you have `abc|def` and that gets handled by your javascript function, then it gets sent to your PHP file. You can do a `split()` in javascript to separate your values, or you can do an `explode()` in PHP. Do you want to post each exploded/split value separately? Do you want to post `abc` and also post `def`?

Comment: `abc` and `def` are two valves in one button, so I'd rathar post `abc|def` first, then `explode()` it. I'm not good at php, but my js is more bad, so I think `explode()` is better. As I mentioned in the question, I want to name a php variable to the ajax show value field. but it is hard to clear the html tag.

Comment: @yuli chika I updated my answer (see above) to include the PHP file.

Comment: @matthewpavkov  thanks a lot, but if this, it just show one php variable in the ajax show value field. I update my code in the question part. This is what I want. post value from index.php, then get the value by self without refresh the page. one botton with two values, I want explode them and finally get `$namea` and `$nameb`. I want use them in other php part.

Comment: @yuli chika So you want both values returned to the HTML document?

Comment: @matthewpavkov Yes, maybe I will add more in the future. I want them returned to the first php page.

Comment: @yuli chika You can't pass values to PHP after the page has loaded. So, if you do an AJAX post to `values.php` from `index.php`, you cannot get those values back and hand it off to PHP in `index.php`. PHP is a server-side language and the page must be served (loaded) in order for the server to process it. There is no way around this. You would need to refresh the page.

Comment: @matthewpavkov Oh,it is poor...this `index.php` is based on a thickbox iframe, it is a sub page, if it refresh, `index.php` will be closed and all the value has gone. do you have any idea to deal with it?

Comment: You'll need to deal with the variable in javascript. Post whatever variable(s) to the PHP file `values.php` and then, for the postback, do as you're already doing. You'll need to get the value in javascript and then do what you want with it from there. You can `split()` the values with javascript http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: Actually, why do you need PHP at all? Is it going to be saved in a database? You don't even need `values.php` at this point, unless you're going to do something server-side.

Comment: @matthewpavkov Yes,the values are saved in a database. Maybe I should do everything in index.php,(delete values.php), and I will study `split()` for more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

by including `$name= "<div id='msg'></div>"` and calling `echo $name`, you're just telling the program to store "" in the $name variable and then print what is stored in that variable. That's why you're getting the unwanted output.

not sure if you're having problems posting the value or showing it in the value, but you need to echo the variable where the userName is stored, may need to send that from the ajax to the php and set it to $name.